# How to set the marker position constant on window resize on google maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I recently started exploring google maps api. I stumbled upon panby function of google maps api. What I am trying to do is, when my map is loaded initially, the marker should be on the right as shown in the attached image.
[Attached screenshot of initial load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/poIix.jpg)

However, I want to add a listener for the marker to stay on the right on window resize but do not know what to write in the listener function .Please help me this. Thanks in advance. Here is my code so far.

```
onAfterRendering: function() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(12.979172,77.715402);
  var mapOptions = {
    center: myLatlng ,
    zoom: 12,
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    zoomControl: true
  };
  var x = this.byId("mapCanvas").getDomRef();
  map = new google.maps.Map(x, mapOptions);

  map.panBy(-300,0); 

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "resize", function() {
    var location= marker.getPosition();
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
  });}
```

Comment: is your trigger executes while resizing?

Comment: Your code seems to be at a minimum missing a closing "}".

Comment: @azad yes the trigger function works if i add map.panBy(-300,0) in the listener funtion but it is not responsive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can recenter the map to the known marker position and then pan left. Something like (untested):

```
...
map.panBy(-300,0); 
var markerLocation= marker.getPosition(); //if you don't have it elsewhere

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "resize", function() {
  map.setCenter(markerLocation)
  map.panBy(-300,0); 
  google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
});}
```